# Como criar uma função no Arduino com argumentos opcionais

Tags: arduino

Gostaria de criar uma função que recebe dois argumentos:
StatusPino(nPino,Valor)
Porém gostaria de, quando enviar somente o número do pino, a função ler o valor lógico do pino e quando eu informar o número do pino COM UM VALOR, a função gravar o valor atual no pino.
Ex:

```
If StatusPino(Sensor1);   // Se o Sensor1 tiver valor HIGH, retorna true 
   // Sensor Ativado
Else
   // Sensor Desativado
```

ou

```
StatusPino(Sensor1,LOW);    // Seta o Sensor1 para LOW e retorna LOW
```

Não encontrei nenhuma função parecida.

Sim, eu poderia fazer 2 funções  LerStatusPino() e GravarStatusPino(), porém estou querendo evitar justamente isso.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tu só precisas declarar a função, como é feito no C, segue uma exemplo.

```
    void StatusPino(int nPino = 0,int Valorint = 0); \\ Declare a funcao com um parametro padrão

    void setup() { 

        pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    }

    void loop() {

        StatusPino(13,1);
        delay(1000); 

        StatusPino(12,1);
        delay(1000); 

        StatusPino(13);
        delay(1000); 

        StatusPino(12);
        delay(1000); 

    }

    void StatusPino(int nPino,int Valorint)
    {

        digitalWrite(nPino, Valorint); 

    }
```